# How to push a view for tap gesture on a View in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to push a View when I tap on an Image.
My Code so far:

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image("image")
                    .onTapGesture {
                   //navigation code here
                }
                Text("Tap on image to find details")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to achieve that navigation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Why can't you use standard NavigationLink as below?

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: SomeDestinationViewHere()) {
            Image("image")
        }
        Text("Tap on image to find details")
    }
}
```

Comment: If I could, I would have.
This image is a member of a nested view. I need to pass along the navigation code from where I want this to happen.

Comment: For the truth I've not got your use-case, but to my mind it is easier to pass image here, which is model data, and use regular approach, than trying to hack system framework. Anyway, it is up to you.

Comment: Okay. If there is no other way, I'll implement NavigationLink.
Thanks for the help! :)